"yaml" shows the user name windows, but I need the value of the name field of the user object
in the application.yaml file:
user:
   name: Bob

the server displays show user name windows "Rus", but I need the value of the name field of the user object "Bob"
@Component
public class ObjectCreator {

    @Value("${user.name}")
    private String name;
    @Value("${user.age}")
    private Integer age;

    @Autowired
    public User createUser( ) {
        return new User(name, age);
    }

